# How to get list of Microsoft Graph API permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to get all Graph API permissions list by an API call or by downloading either XML or JSON file.

I tried to check call made from Azure portal when list is loaded but nothing.

Does someone know how we can get this info from Microsoft?

Comment: Here's the Script to list all delegated permissions and application permissions in Azure AD This might be helpful, https://gist.github.com/psignoret/41793f8c6211d2df5051d77ca3728c09

Comment: thanks for answers but it's not exactly what i was seeking about.
In fact, i want to get list we can find here [Graph api permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#all-permissions-and-ids)
but throught an automatic way (Api, Json or Xml file and not by parsing an Html page :). Idealy with extra info if existing to let my users filter them easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Graph API `/servicePrincipals` [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and filter `Microsoft Graph` app.

The result will contain list of application and delegated permissions including description and other details.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId+eq+'00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'&$select=displayName,appId,appRoles,oauth2PermissionScopes,servicePrincipalType
```

Result

```
{
    "displayName": "Microsoft Graph",
    "appId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
    "servicePrincipalType": "Application",
    "value": [
        {
            "appRoles": [
                {
                    "allowedMemberTypes": [
                        "Application"
                    ],
                    "description": "Allows the app to read all available Teams Templates, without a signed-user.",
                    "displayName": "Read all available Teams Templates",
                    "id": "6323133e-1f6e-46d4-9372-ac33a0870636",
                    "isEnabled": true,
                    "origin": "Application",
                    "value": "TeamTemplates.Read.All"
                },
                ...
            ],
            "oauth2PermissionScopes": [
                {
                    "adminConsentDescription": "Allows the app to read the available Teams templates, on behalf of the signed-in user.",
                    "adminConsentDisplayName": "Read available Teams templates",
                    "id": "cd87405c-5792-4f15-92f7-debc0db6d1d6",
                    "isEnabled": true,
                    "type": "User",
                    "userConsentDescription": "Read available Teams templates, on your behalf.",
                    "userConsentDisplayName": "Read available Teams templates",
                    "value": "TeamTemplates.Read"
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

`appRoles` property represents application permissions

`oauth2PermissionScopes` property represents delegated permissions

The endpoint requires `Application.Read.All`, `Application.ReadWrite.All`, `Directory.Read.All`, `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permissions

I've compared data returned by the query above with the list in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#all-permissions-and-ids) and it matches.

Answer (score 0):

Api permissions can be listed by using following query in microsoft graph api.[Microsoft graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

***Directory.Read.All*** permission is required to be granted admin consent authenticate a Microsoft Graph API client to access the `/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants` endpoint.

[image]

Then make a GET request  to
***`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants`***

**Result:** Represents delegated permissions which have been granted for client applications to access APIs on behalf of signed-in users.

```
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#oauth2PermissionGrants",
"@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants?$skiptoken=xxxx",
"value": [
    {
        "clientId": "xxx",
        "consentType": "Principal",
        "id": "YBLh22Q2xxxxxxZPqphjW",
        "principalId": "xxxx",
        "resourceId": "xxxxxx",
        "scope": "UserProfile.Read "
    },
    {
        "clientId": "xxxx",
        "consentType": "Principal",
        "id": "xxxx",
        "principalId": "xxxx6efe7a",
        "resourceId": "xxxxx",
        "scope": "UserProfile.Read "
    },
    {
        "clientId": "xxxx",
        "consentType": "Principal",
        "id": "YBLh2xxxxxmX",
        "principalId": "xxxxxxx",
        "resourceId": "xxxx",
        "scope": "UserProfile.Read "
    },
    {
        "clientId": "xxxxx",
        "consentType": "Principal",
        "id": "YBLh22Q2xxxxxxN2iXWD",
        "principalId": "xxxxx",
        "resourceId": "xxxx",
        "scope": "UserProfile.Read"
    },
    {
        "clientId": "xxxxx",
        "consentType": "Principal",
        "id": "YBLh22Q2xExxxxbjbxXaqHKDW",
        "principalId": "xxxx",
        "resourceId": "xxxxx",
        "scope": "UserProfile.Read"
    },
    {
        "clientId": "xxxxxxx",
        "consentType": "Principal",
        "id": "xxxxxxxx",
        "principalId": "xxx",
        "resourceId": "bbf1c2f4xxxxxxxx",
        "scope": "user_impersonation "
    },
    {
        "clientId": "xxxx-60ae65bca24f",
        "consentType": "Principal",
        "id": "xxxx_AXxTLAO2AAHbv56",
        "principalId": "941ea60dxxxxxx-d800076efe7a",
        "resourceId": "bbf1c2f4xxxxx",
        "scope": "user_impersonation "
    },
    {
        "clientId": "xxxx9-60ae65bca24f",
        "consentType": "Principal",
        "id": "xxx",
        "principalId": "xxx",
        "resourceId": "bbf1c2f4-xxxxx",
        "scope": "user_impersonation"
    },
    {
        "clientId": "dbe11260-3664-40c4-ae39-60ae65bca24f",
        "consentType": "Principal",
        "id": "xxxx",
        "principalId": "d1de0f56-d471-4580-b8db-c576aa1ca0d6",
        "resourceId": "bbf1c2f4-52df-4d28-8dea-e8de231ed902",
        "scope": "user_impersonation"
    }
```

[image]

**Reference:** [List oAuth2PermissionGrants (delegated permission grants) - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no list by an api call or by downloading XML or JSon file available right now, if you want this API , you can raise a [feature request](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) here.